# Is possible to use push method with objects ?

Tags: javascript

As you can see in the following code the method works with an object, why does it work,? is it because I am accessing the name which is an array ?

```
var person = {
    name : []
};

person["name"].push('Mark');
```

Comment: exactly, `person["name"]` is an array. It's pretty obvious

Comment: You're not using `push` on an object, just the array it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, the object contains a property named 'name' which is an array object. You can reference this in 2 different ways. By name and by property.

```
person.name.push('Mark')
```

would work as well as

```
person['name'].push('Mark')
```

The great thing about javascript objects is that you can add any type of object to a javascript object's structure.

Your javascript object just happens to contain an array object which can be pushed to like a normal array.

Comment: There is no JSON in the question.

Comment: Mr. technicality over here. Congratulations you know that javascript has a native object type that is virtually the exact same as a JSON object with minor differences. Nice.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Note that there are many non-trivial differences between JavaScript objects and JSON and your second to last sentence is completely incorrect.

Comment: Downvote for the snarky comments. JSON is not a JavaScript object, is it a technicality? Kind like Java is not JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can access object properties in two ways:

```
objectName.propertyName
```

or

```
objectName["propertyName"]
```